# CalcInterior expression help in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression

In QGIS on a new layer I'm trying to calculate the area of certain landtypes individually from a Grounds Maintenance layer. Previously I have used the following expression in Cadcorp SIS:

```
CalcInterior(Overlay('Grounds Maintenance',{Landtype$='Grass'}),'_area$',1)
```

Which works fine in Cadcorp,but I don't know how to write the same expression to work in QGIS.

Comment: Guessing from your description, I would first calculate the area for each feature using the **Field Calculator** with expression `$area`. Then I would use the **Group Stats** plugin (which you can download from the toolbar _Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins_) to **sum** the area based on _Landtype_.

Comment: Another good plugin to do that (and much more!) is the LecoS! This is for landscape statistics (like fragstats in Qgis).

Comment: Thanks Joseph that tool's really helpful. I forgot to explain in a bit more detail. I have one layer called GM Boundaries (the layer I need the area calculation information for) which is drawings boundaries over the Grounds Maintenance layer. I want the grounds maintenance landtypes within this boundary calculated

Comment: @KRickard - I would probably use the **Join attributes by location** tool (_Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location_) using the GM Boundaries layer as the target layer. Enable the _Keep all records_ setting which will create a copy of the target layer and with attributes from the Grounds Maintenance layer (i.e. your boundaries should have a landtype). Then use the **Group Stats** plugin to sum the area (you may have to recalculate `$area` in the new output layer if you haven't saved this in the original).